# Special character $ in a shell script

Tags: shell

I would like to write the $ symbol in a shell script.
I use echo for doing it, but now I need that special character in order to load
the text file and compute a plot modifying the columns in gnuplot

Thanks in advance,
Adrian

Comment: in bash shell you can escape most characters with a `\ ` example `\$ ` or `\\ `

Comment: To expand on that you can enter a command like `echo \$` to have the literal value `$` printed

Answer (score 0):

try using `"\$"` instead of `"$"`, escape the character $